# Removing number from bibliography title

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, numbering

I am using the following commands to rename the title of the bibliography, and I declare the bibliography in this style:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{article}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\refname}{Irodalomjegyzék}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Irodalomjegyzék}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% ...

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
    % bibitems
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, LaTeX prints a number before the title "Irodalomjegyzék", in the document and also in the ToC.

[image: Bibliography title with trailing quad]

How can I remove the number from the title?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It seems you're using both an [embedded system](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Embedded_system) *and* BibTeX. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I am completely new to LaTex, i've just found this solution and it worked... I edited my question with the thing you asked, i hope i included everything which is important.

Comment: I also removed BibTex, it seems that is completely unused in my doc. I do not know why i added that...

Comment: The `article` class doesn't define any `openright` option, but the `book` class does. Are you sure you don't want to use `book` instead?

Comment: I don't think so, this is a thesis. Somebody suggested me to use the the `openright` option, because he said it need for the binding offset. I just removed the option, it also did not make a difference.

BTW, i found the answer for my actual question: i had to remove th `numbib` option from the `tocbibind` package!

Comment: I don't think you should use `article` for a thesis. Use `book`, `report`, `memoir`, or some other class specifically geared towards a thesis.

Comment: remove the `numbib` option of `tocbibind` package. See section 2 of the `tocbibind` manual. (`texdoc tocbibind`)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a wrong use of a package (not looking at the basic documentation of the package)